# ¿Como valido la contraseña que ingrese con la que tengo encriptada en la base de datos mysql?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

El asunto es que tengo un problema no se si sea con la sentencia del `password_verify()` o con el arreglo asociativo al usuario con el que se desea loguear y es que al parecer no me está validando la contraseña que tengo encriptada en las base de datos mysql, ya que yo hago el registro de un usuario de forma normal y le asigno una contraseña, ahora cuando intento loguearme, no me deja acceder con la contraseña que yo le especifiqué al momento del registro

Aquí les comparto el código PHP ya que lo he intentado de varias formas y no me está resultando.

```
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$password = $_POST['password'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email'";
$login = mysqli_query($parametros, $sql);
if ($login && mysqli_num_rows($login) == 1) {
    $usuarios = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login);
    // Con el segundo argumento accedemos a la contraseña cifrada que está en la BD
    $verificar_password = password_verify($password, $usuarios['password']);
    var_dump($verificar_password);
    die();
    if ($verificar_password) {
        $_SESSION['usuarios'] = $usuarios;
        $_SESSION['loginvalido'] = "Accediste con exito";
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['errorlogin'] = "No pudiste acceder";
    }
}
else{
    $_SESSION['errorlogin'] = "No pudiste acceder";
}
```

PD: La variable parámetros es la que hace la conexión a la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? ¿Cómo has hasheado la contraseña almacenada en la base de datos? Por evitar la función `password_verify()`, ¿por qué no vuelves a hashear la contraseña del POST y la comparas directamente con la almacenada?

Comment: La contraseña la he cifrado de la siguiente forma.  // cifrar la contraseña dentro de la base de datos
        $password_seguro = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost'=>4]);
        //var_dump(password_verify($password, $password_seguro));
        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES(null, '$nombre', '$apellido', '$email', '$password_seguro')";
        $guardar = mysqli_query($parametros, $sql);

Comment: @JoseQuintero ya solucionaste con mi respuesta?

Comment: Si amigo, seguí tus pasos y si me deja acceder con la contraseña que establecí al momento de hacer el registro al mismo tiempo que la valida con la contraseña encriptada en la BD, te lo agradezco mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vas en el camino correcto, pero hay que hacer algunas validaciones en la lógica de programación que implementas.

Algunos puntos para solucionar el problema pueden ser:

1. Asegúrate de que estés almacenando la contraseña de forma segura en la base de datos utilizando la función `password_hash()` al momento del registro. Por ejemplo:

```
$password_cifrada = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
// Guardar $password_cifrada en la base de datos
```

2. Verifica que el campo password en la tabla de la base de datos tenga la longitud suficiente para almacenar correctamente la contraseña cifrada. La longitud recomendada es 60 caracteres o más.
3. Asegúrate de que la variable ***$password*** contenga el valor correcto al momento de realizar la verificación. Puedes agregar un `echo $password;` antes de la línea $verificar_password = password_verify($password, `$usuarios['password']);` para verificar que el valor sea el esperado.
4. Comprueba si estás obteniendo correctamente los datos del usuario de la base de datos. Puedes agregar un `var_dump($usuarios);` después de `$usuarios = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login);` para verificar si se están obteniendo los datos esperados.
5. Verifica que estés utilizando sesiones correctamente y que se haya iniciado una sesión antes de intentar establecer las variables `$_SESSION['usuarios']` y `$_SESSION['loginvalido']`. Puedes agregar un `session_start();` al principio del archivo para asegurarte de que la sesión esté iniciada.

Es importante que hagas un debug paso a paso de todo lo que te he mencionado, de seguro uno de los puntos podrá solucionar el problema.

yo utilizo una clase especial para la el manejo de contraseñas:

```
<?php

class Password_Handler
{
    //genera automaticamente una contraseña por defecto
    public function Default_Password()
    {
        $characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        $defpassword = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 8; ++$i) {
            $defpassword .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
        }

        return $defpassword;
    }

    //encripta una contraseña y retorna el hash que se debe guardar en la base de datos
    public function Encript_Password($password)
    {
        return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => C_CICLE]);
    }

    //toma el hash guardado en la base de datos que se le pasa y hace una comparacion vs el password escrito por el usuario
    public function validate_Password($password, $hash)
    {
        return password_verify($password, $hash);
    }

}
```

Tambien ten en cuenta que si haces:

```
var_dump($verificar_password);
die(); // aqui se detiene todo el script php y nada de lo que le sigue se ejecutara.
```